# What is the fastest way to generate pseudo random number by 8-bit MCU?

Tags: c, random, microcontroller, 8051, 8-bit

[Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is a good algorithm. But is there any faster algorithm?

Comment: As far as quality/performance goes, LCG is pretty good. I know of no faster algorithm that does not at the same time drastically lower the quality of the generated data.

Comment: MWC is fast as well, and has a longer period. Requires saving some extra state, though.

Comment: What kind of random numbers do you need, and for what purpose? It matters for choosing a good algorithm.

Comment: It would be hard to get too much faster than a multiply, add, and divide (especially since the division can usually be omitted by just truncating the result of the multiply/add operations to a certain number of bits).

Comment: @Michael Burr Even multiplication is often expensive on 8-bit CPUs.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker As per my answer, below, I took your advice and made up some [example](https://github.com/sh1boot/8bitrand/blob/master/examples.c) implementions which I believe should outperform LCG and LFSR (on **both** quality and speed) on 8-bit MCUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall, [8051](/questions/tagged/8051) has an 8x8=16-bit multiplier, so it might be feasible to implement a lag-n [multiply-with-carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry) generator.  The advantage of this technique is that if you can find a suitable safe prime, you can get a very long period with very little arithmetic.

Unfortunately, there don't seem to be an awful lot of safe-prime options with a multiplier that is only eight bits, and I fear the short multiplier may result in some weaknesses that don't normally show up with MWC.

I just knocked this together, and while I'm not 100% certain it implements MWC correctly, it actually passes a surprising number of [dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) tests:

```
#define STATE_BYTES 7
#define MULT 0x13B /* for STATE_BYTES==6 only */
#define MULT_LO (MULT & 255)
#define MULT_HI (MULT & 256)

uint8_t rand8(void)
{
    static uint8_t state[STATE_BYTES] =
    { 0x87, 0xdd, 0xdc, 0x10, 0x35, 0xbc, 0x5c };
    static uint16_t c = 0x42;
    static int i = 0;
    uint16_t t;
    uint8_t x;

    x = state[i];
    t = (uint16_t)x * MULT_LO + c;
    c = t >> 8;
#if MULT_HI
    c += x;
#endif
    x = t & 255;
    state[i] = x;
    if (++i >= sizeof(state))
        i = 0;
    return x;
}
```

As you can see, the multiplier is actually nine bits, but we use a shift-and-add to implement that last bit which the hardware multiplier can't manage.

On further testing, I've found a suitable safe prime of 89 bits which does pass almost all of dieharder.  Change these lines:

```
#define STATE_BYTES 10
#define MULT 0x153 /* for STATE_BYTES==10 only */
```

and I used this seed for testing:

```
static uint8_t state[STATE_BYTES] =
{ 0x87, 0xdd, 0xdc, 0x10, 0x35, 0xbc, 0x5c, 0xb6, 0xca, 0x0a, };
static uint16_t c = 0x42;
```

The seed is just some bits from /dev/random, and you're free to choose your own.  However, increasing the state size is basically cheating, because it allows the quality of the seed to play a greater role in the success or failure in randomness tests.  It may be that bad seeds could result in not-very-random results.

Comment: This problem interested me, so I made a [test app](https://github.com/sh1boot/8bitrand) around it and started surveying the coefficients to see what does well.

Answer (score 4):

Since 8-bit CPUs typically can't do fast division or even multiplication, it is often not a good idea to use a linear congruential generator.

[Linear feedback shift register (LFSR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) uses only shift and logical operations.

If you use an array it becomes the Generalized Linear Feedback Shift Register (GLFSR), the general method that the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) uses.  It cycles through the array instead of shifting all the bits at each step, so that you can have a large state space (hundreds to thousands of bits) with very little computational effort.

Note that since it is a linear method it is not suitable for cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no good significantly faster algorithms via general purpose CPUs.  As mentioned by @Joachim Isaksson and @Michael Burr, there is not much that can be done without driving down quality or doing something weird e. g: compute at compile time a huge list of random numbers, then run-time generation is fast.

Any real fast random number generator uses specialized hardware.  Since you have tagged [microcontroller], check out the processor you are using to see what specialized features it may provide.

Further: providing some more info to your PRN need may help elicit some novel ideas (number length, speed: O(n) or time, degree of randomness, etc.) like using a micro-controller's time based counter modded by a big prime.